# Insert data to array php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have this code:

```
$rows = array();

      $table = array();
      foreach($kol as $r) {
          $temp = array();
          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
          $m = array('label' => (string) $r['naziv'], 'type' => 'string'); 
        $rows[] = ($m);
        }


    $table['cols'] =  $rows;
```

and I get this json:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Pera Peric","type":"string"},{"label":"IMT 510-td","type":"string"},{"label":"Laza Lazic","type":"string"}
```

How I can put data on $m array to position 0 to get json like this:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Datum,"type":"Date"},{"label":"Pera Peric","type":"string"},{"label":"IMT 510-td","type":"string"},{"label":"Laza Lazic","type":"string"}
```

so here I just want to add this data: `{"label":"Datum,"type":"Date"} to array ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it before you start your loop (I cleaned a bit):

```
$rows = array();
$table = array();

$rows[] = array('label' => 'Datum', 'type' => 'Date')

foreach ($kol as $r) {
    $rows[] = array('label' => (string) $r['naziv'], 'type' => 'string');
}

$table['cols'] =  $rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

### array_unshift()

```
<?php

// your json
$json = '{"cols":[{"label":"Pera Peric","type":"string"},{"label":"IMT 510-td","type":"string"},{"label":"Laza Lazic","type":"string"}]}';

// json array to php array using json_decode()
$json_decode = json_decode($json, true);

// your $m php array
$m = array(
  'label' => 'Datum',
  'type' => 'Date'
);

// add you $m to position 0 in index 'cols'
array_unshift($json_decode['cols'], $m);
```

Done!

```
array(1) {
  ["cols"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(5) "Datum"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "Date"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(10) "Pera Peric"
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "string"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(10) "IMT 510-td"
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "string"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(10) "Laza Lazic"
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Back to json (if you want)

```
$json = json_encode($json_decode);
```